# How will Admin be able to see the live communication of customer and agent in his portal in bot framework?

Tags: c#, botframework

I developed a bot application in microsoft bot framework in which customer escalates his call to agent. For this I have implemented Tompanna solution.
But now, I wanted to build a admin portal where admin could see the live communication happening b/w customer and agent. So, how I'll achieve this?

Comment: Link tot the Tompanna solution?

Comment: Tompanna solution link :  https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample

Answer (score 0):

> But now, I wanted to build a admin portal where admin could see the live communication happening b/w customer and agent. So, how I'll achieve this?

With that sample, you would just use another channel to view it. In [the example](https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample#testing-the-hand-off), they are using Teams. If you want this in your own portal, you could just add [Web Chat](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-webchat) to any page.

Another route you *could* go, if you want to just watch or review the conversations, would be to implement transcript logging. This would allow you to build a portal that could see more than just the live conversation (actually, i'm not sure how 'live' you could get with this solution). You would need to write code to retrieve the transcripts from blob storage and then then render that as you wish.

**Transcript logging in Blob storage:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#blob-transcript-storage

**More info on transcript logging:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-debug-transcript?view=azure-bot-service-4.0